# What's the difference between shokumotsu (食物) and tabemono (食べ物),

Tags: word-choice, words, food, conversations

They both convey the meaning of "meal" or "food", but I don't know which one I should use. Which ones would be used most of the time for everyday-conversations? Would these two sentences mean the same?

> [食物を食べる]{しょくもつをたべる}
>
> [食べ物を食べる]{たべものをたべる}

Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For everyday conversations use たべもの。
しょくもつ is more formal and not used in casual situations, unless it is part of an expression like 食物繊維.

As a general rule, 音読み words are more used in formal, written language, while 訓読み words are more used in informal, spoken language.

Comment: I think this is not unlike germanic vs. latin words in english.